# Extrapolate missing data for each group by average percentage of change

Tags: r, percentage, extrapolation

I have a data frame containing average income by zip code, for the years 2010-2014. I want data for the years 2015-2017, so I'm looking for a way to extrapolate this based on the yearly average change of each zip code group for the years available.

For example:

```
year  zip   income
2010  1111   5000
2011  1111   5500
2012  1111   6000
2013  1111   6500
2014  1111   7000
2010  2222   5000
2011  2222   6000
2012  2222   7000
2013  2222   8000
2014  2222   9000
```

Should (roughly) have:

```
year  zip   income
2010  1111   5000
2011  1111   5500
2012  1111   6000
2013  1111   6500
2014  1111   7000
2015  1111   7614
2016  1111   8282
2017  1111   9009
2010  2222   5000
2011  2222   6000
2012  2222   7000
2013  2222   8000
2014  2222   9000
2015  2222   10424
2016  2222   12074
2017  2222   13986
```

Based on an average growth of 8.78% for zip code 1111 and 15.83% for zip code 2222.

Comment: Try `?approx` with `method="linear"`.

Comment: while I didn't know this function, this didn't get me very far, as I don't manage to create new years within a data frame, and interpolate based on groups.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very quick messy data.table idea

```
library(data.table)

#Create data
last_year <- 2014 
dt <- data.table(year=rep(2010:last_year,2),
             zip=c(rep(1111,5),rep(2222,5)),
             income=c(seq(5000,7000,500),seq(5000,9000,1000)))

#Future data
dt_fut <- data.table(year=rep((last_year+1):2017,2),
           zip=c(rep(1111,3),rep(2222,3)),
           income=rep(NA_integer_,6))

#calculate mean percentage change per year
dt[,avg_growth:=mean(diff(log(income))),by=zip]
#bind old with future data
dt <- rbindlist(list(dt,dt_fut),fill=T);setorder(dt,zip,year)

#carry last value forward replace NA 
dt[,avg_growth:=na.locf(avg_growth),by=zip][,income:=na.locf(income),by=zip]

#calculate
# after 2014+1 (2015) then replace income 
# with income*cumulative product of the average growth (1+r)-1
dt[year>=last_year+1,income:=income*cumprod(1+avg_growth)-1,by=zip][]
```